# Bluetooth error status 133

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any possibility to check why and where is the problem?

I have phone and BLE device.
I'm trying to establish connection between devices but sometimes getting GAT_ERROR(133).

**Can I somehow check if it is problem with Bluetooth on Phone or something with Blouetooth on the device?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should describe more specifically. Normally You can have a look at http://mangoprojects.info/arduino/android-wireless-remote-switch-control-home-appliances-android-bluetooth-arduino/